# I get an error in visual studio 2017 using the header stdafx.h in the code

Tags: c++

Here is the code. I'm getting the following error, what am I doing wrong? I'm using visual studio 2017.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Print1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>Print1.cpp
>   1>c:\users\kiwiblazer\source\repos\print1\print1\print1.cpp(4): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?
>   1>Done building project "Print1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    cout << "Never fear, C++ is here! ";
    return 0;
```

Comment: Next time try doing a search on the exact error before asking here. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error log says `Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"'`. This is because they changed the precompiled headers name to `pch.h.` for VS17

Try replacing `stdafx.h` with `pch.h`. I think that would be the easiest workaround.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Never fear, C++ is here! ";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Please post complete code. for example closing bracket of main is missing in the code and that might be the reason for failure.

If your code is correct then please check Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers properties of your solution and change your pre compile header files accordingly.